# Laravel Localization Nested JSON Language File

Tags: php, json, laravel, localization

I'm trying to make my project multi-language.

I want to work with JSON files since my project has lots of pages,so a lot of strings to translate.

In order to avoid confusion I want to use nested JSON objects instead of just keys.

For example my en.json file looking like this:

```
{
    "login": {
        "login": "Login",
        "email": "Email",
        "emailPlaceholder": "Registered email address",
        "password": "Password",
        "passwordPlaceHolder": "Your account password"
    },

   "dashboard": {}
}
```

So I want to have a key for each page.

But when I use it on the view files, it reads just as a regular string:

```
<label for="email">
    {{ __('login.email') }}
</label>
```

[image]

Any help would be nice, thank you very much.

Comment: Based on [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php#L106) comment in the translation method, nested translations in json are not supported, you should use a PHP array if you want to use nested translations.

Comment: Read Here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization. Laravel uses arrays instead of JSON. You are free to do nesting also.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
<label for="email">
    {{ __('login')['email'] }}
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get this approach by changing the default `__` helper by:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr; 

function __($key = null, $replace = [], $locale = null)
{
    // Default behavior
    if (is_null($key)) return $key;        
    if (trans()->has($key)) return trans($key, $replace, $locale);

    // Search in .json file
    $search = Arr::get(trans()->get('*'), $key);
    if ($search !== null) return $search;

    // Return .json fallback
    $fallback = Arr::get(trans()->get('*', [], config('app.fallback_locale')), $key);
    if ($fallback !== null) return $fallback;

    // Return key name if not found
    else return $key;
}
```

### Creating custom bootstrap helpers

if you dont know how to change the default helper, create a file with any name (ex: `bootstrap/helpers.php`), then in the file `public/index.php` add this line just before 'Register The Auto Loader'

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Custom Helpers
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/helpers.php';
```

### (Optional) Variables feature

if you also want to use the **Variables** feature, just like `__(welcome.user, ['user'=>'david'])` you must create a new helper on that file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

function trans_replacements($line, array $replace)
{
    if (empty($replace)) return $line;

    $shouldReplace = [];

    foreach ($replace as $key => $value) {
        $shouldReplace[':'.Str::ucfirst($key)] = Str::ucfirst($value);
        $shouldReplace[':'.Str::upper($key)] = Str::upper($value);
        $shouldReplace[':'.$key] = $value;
    }

    return strtr($line, $shouldReplace);
}
```

and then replace `return $search` with `trans_replacements($search, $replace)` and `return $fallback` with `trans_replacements($fallback, $replace)`

### (Optional) Countable feature

for **Countable** feature (ex: `'an apple|many apples'`), is the same process, just add this helper:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

function trans_choice($key, $number, array $replace = [], $locale = null)
{        
    // Get message
    $message = __($key, $replace, $locale);

    // If the given "number" is actually an array or countable we will simply count the
    // number of elements in an instance.
    if (is_array($number) || $number instanceof Countable) 
    $number = count($number);

    $replace['count'] = $number;

    return trans_replacements(
        trans()->getSelector()->choose($message, $number, $locale = App::getLocale()), 
        $replace
    );
}
```

### Bootstrap Helpers File

here is the file, just in case: [bendeckdavid/laravel_locale_nested_json](https://github.com/bendeckdavid/laravel_locale_nested_json/blob/main/bootstrap/helpers.php)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel not supporting this by default is annoying.
However, you can use this function I made:

```
function ___($path) {
        $properties = explode(".", $path);
        $base = __($properties[0]);
        unset($properties[0]);
        foreach($properties as $property) {
            // Allows specification of indexes
            if(is_numeric($property)) {
                $property = intval($property);
            }
            // If the key has not been found, return the initial parameter like __()
            try {
                $base = $base[$property];
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                return $path;
            }
        }
        return $base;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are someone like me stumbling upon here wanting to use a file structure like below without the need to specify keys for each string when using php language files.

```
-app
-lang
  --fr
    ---Headers.json
```

A little modification to David G's answer above,

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Arr; 

function ___($path = null, $replace = [], $locale = null)
{
    // Default behavior
    if (is_null($path)) return $path;
    if(!strrpos($path, '.')) {
        return  $path;
    }

    $properties = explode(".", $path);
    $currentLocale = app()->getLocale();    

    // If the file/folder doesn't exist 
    // return the last part of the dot notation
    $translated_string = substr($path, strrpos($path, '.') + 1);

    if(is_dir(lang_path($currentLocale))) {
        if (is_file(lang_path($currentLocale.'\\'.$properties[0].'.json'))) {
            $contents = json_decode(file_get_contents(lang_path($currentLocale.'\\'.$properties[0].'.json')), true);
            // If no value exists for the key, the key is itself returned
            $translated_string = Arr::get($contents, $properties[1], $properties[1]);
        }
    }

    return $translated_string;
}
```

As of now this doesn't work for files under subdirectories under the locale folder. I am sure, the above code can be optimized, but this should give you an idea.

Also, this function uses triple-underscore `{{___()}}` instead of the regular double-underscore `{{__()}}` to avoid conflicts.

Works for,

```
{{___('Messages.Welcome') }} // lang/(locale)/Messages.json
{{___('Welcome')}} // lang/(locale).json
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming your json is stored in `$json`, you want to parse it into array by using `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

You can access it by:

```
<label for="email">
    {{ $data['login']['emailPlaceholder'] }}
</label>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the question asked except it shares the word 'JSON'.